# node-opcua-samples - simple_client.js does not connect to simple_server.js

Tags: node.js, node-opcua

i'm trying to gain deeper knowledge of using opc. So i installed node js and then *node-opcua-samples* via npm.

Afterwards i went to powershell, changed cwd to the bin directory of *node-opcua-samples* and started simple_server.js with

`node simple_server.js`

The server is starting and prints

`server now waiting for connections. CTRL+C to stop`

to the console. Then it prints

`contacting discovery server backoff  opc.tcp://localhost:4840  attempt # 0  retrying in  2  seconds
server registration is still pending (is Local Discovery Server up and running ?)`

From the output i expect to be able to connect to the running server, even though it shows the warning concerning the discovery server. Am i right?

The next step is to start *simple_client.js* in a second powershell by changeing the cwd to the bin directory of *node-opcua-samples* and then use

`node simple_client.js >endpointUrl printed by server<`

At this point i'm expecting the client to connect to the started server and complete the test cases build in. But the client seemingly is not able to connect to the server and prints

`backoff attempt # 0  retrying in  2  seconds`

Following the hint given inside of *simple_client.js* and running *simple_client_ts.ts* with ts-node results in the same behavior.

So where is my mistake?

Any hints or questions will be appreciated.

Regards
Gregor

Systemdetails for reproduction:

`Windows 10
Node Version 12.13.0
node-opcua-samples Version 2.5.7`

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i solved the problem....

Instead of using the endpointUrl printed by the server, i had to start the client with the endpoint `opc.tcp://localhost:26543`. The used port is the default port set in simple_server.js.

The warning about the discovery server vanished after setting `registerServerMethod` in simple_server.js from `RegisterServerMethod.LDS` to `RegisterServerMethod.HIDDEN`.

Best regards
Gregor